# I’m trying to compile prusaslicer and SuperSlicer on Rpi 4b with 8 gb memory - swap file question

Tags: pi-4, swap-space

I’ve noticed that partway thru the process, the makes seem to stall and the desktop is unresponsive.  I’m thinking that I need to increase swap space.   My Pi boots from kingston ssd attached via usb 3.

Is there any reason why I shouldn’t increase swap on boot ssd. Most all of my user files are on WiFi connected NAS.